# ejabberd external auth and getting list of registered users or searching for user?

Tags: authentication, ejabberd

We have an existing set of web applications written in .NET (front ends and web services) with SQL Server back end. Trying to switch from Openfire as XMPP server to ejabberd. Openfire allows to delegate user authentication to existing database through using SQL queries stored in openfire.ofProperty database table.
With ejabberd I was hoping to either
1) Delegate ejabberd user authentication / management to our system by using external script auth (or equivalent ejabberd_auth_http module)
Or
2) Synchronizing ejabberd user authentication / management with our system using ejabberd ReST API.

I tried external auth, it works, but its [API](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/guide/#external) does not provide any methods for getting the list of registered users and for user search. So, after switching to external auth "registered_users" command doesn't work anymore. I presume [Jabber Search](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0055.html) won't work either: how could you search if you cannot get a list to search in?

So, is the only way to integrate ejabberd-based chat with an existing system's user base through [ejabberd ReST API](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/)?  I mean: when our system registers a user it would call ejabberd ReST API "register" command, etc.  This would duplicate our system's "users" table in ejabberd's "users" table, but at least keep them synchronized...